# Slow loading shiny apps

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have installed shiny-server on a remote Centos server.
The shiny config looks like this:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as <user>;
# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
listen 3838;
# Define a location at the base URL
location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
directory_index on;
}
}
```

whenever I place the shiny app file on the `/srv/shiny-server` folder, it loads well.
But I tried to create a folder and then use file paths to call different apps but they take forever to load.

Is there something am missing in order to use paths to deploy multiple apps in one server?

Comment: you should place apps in a possibly hierarchical structure underneath `/srv/shiny-server`. E.g `/srv/shiny-server/app1/app.R` will be accessible at http://localhost:3838/app1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later came to find out that the faster way was creating a folder in `/srv/shiny-server`and then adding a symbolic link to: `/opt/shiny-server/foldername` 
You will then store your apps in the second location and call them from the first one.
The speed of loading was now a bit better. Ofcourse it will also depend on how efficient your code is.